# Trying to format USB (using Linux/fdisk) so it shows up on my Mac

Tags: hard-drive, usb, startup, partition, unix

I have a USB drive that I can see/access/modify/etc in Linux/Ubuntu but it doesn't show up on my Mac OSX.

I did `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb` (where my USB is) and then `g` to create a new GPT partition table, `n` to make a new partition, used all default settings, then `w` to save and exit.

Then I did `sudo mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sdb1` to format the partition with a FAT32 filesystem.

I ejected the USB and put it in my Mac and it doesn't show up / get detected.

What did I miss?

Comment: Try simple `sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1` and don't forget unmount before and after ;)

Comment: I think your problem was not specifying a `Partition Type` that macOS would recognise. I made an answer that works with an `exFat` formatted USB drive.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the original question:

This answer uses the exFat file system type instead of Fat32.

See [this link](https://newtocode.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/format-usb-as-exfat-in-ubuntu-13-10-terminal/) for instructions about how to create an exFAT USB drive, ***from within Linux***, that will show up in macOS, Linux and Windows.

Use `lsusb` and `blkid -o list` and `df -h` to work out the device block of your Linux attached USB drive (e.g: /dev/sdb)

1. Install exfat utilities in Linux (e.g: Ubuntu in this case)

   `sudo apt update && sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`
2. Use fdisk to partition the USB drive.

   `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`
3. Create a new partition table and clear all current partition data.
   Type `o` at the prompt for a `MBR partition table` or `g` for a `GUID Partition Table (GPT)`.
4. Create a new partition (In this case ONE partition for the whole drive).
   Type `n`. It will ask for some values which you can simply press enter for the default values.
5. Change the partition Type
   When you run `fdisk` in Linux OS a new partition is given the partition `Type` of `Linux` by default. macOS will not recognise that. To change the partition Type flag to `exFat` we have to type in the command `t`.  Fdisk will now ask for a number indicating the flag you want to set. We want number `7` for `HPFS/NTFS/exfat`. (You can see all the flags by typing `L`).
6. Save the Partition table information.
   Write the settings to the USB drive by typing the command `w` in fdisk.
7. Create a filesystem (exFat).
   Now we have a partition but no filesystem yet so make one like this:
   `sudo mkfs.exfat /dev/sdb1`

Now data you save to this drive will be available in macOS, Windows and Linux

Comment: If anyone is still having issues, this answer helped me format my USB drive with two small changes: in step 3. I use `g` for the `GUID Partition Table (GPT)` and not `o` for the `MBR partition table` and in step 5. I use number `11` which is `Microsoft basic data` instead of `HPFS/NTFS/exfat`. My USB drive can now be read by both, Linux and MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using MAC**

- Open `Disk Utility` from `Lauchpad`
- Select Your `USB Disk` Form top left corner

[image]

-Select `Partition` Option

[image]

-Crate choose `1 Partition` fill Name, and Format details

[image]

-Then Click  `apply`

[image]

-Wait till it  the details

-Then select `Disk Partition` and `Erase` It.

[image]

[image]

After completing these steps you can access your USB drive on MAC,
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Mahesh, OP uses Linux to format USB which Mac cannot see then. He doesn't need instructions on how to format USB drive on Mac... :)

Comment: Sorry, My bad :( , I also some times ago had same problem, it did not solved by formatting on linux, but solved by formatting on MAC

Comment: You are correct, this could be the solution :)))

Comment: @DenisRasulev :)

Comment: I can get it to work if I format it on the Mac but this doesn't explain why it doesn't work from Linux

Comment: @user261985  may be your are missing some step in command, try gpatrted  GUI on Ubuntu , if it did helped you please upvote and accept